# how do I get the minutes/hours financial data with rows summary using Python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming, finance

Supposed I have some financial data of minutes as below, I would like to write a user-defined function(below code is ugly and complicated), how do I get the 5-minute/10-minute/30-minute/1 hour/8 hour/24 hours data with rows summary using Python/pandas out of CSV?

```
    TIME     OPEN    HIGH    LOW     CLOSE   VOLUME
         ----------------------------------------------
0   1592194620 3046.00 3048.50 3046.00 3047.50 505          
1   1592194630 3047.00 3048.00 3046.00 3047.00 162          
2   1592194640 3047.50 3048.00 3047.00 3047.50 98           
3   1592194650 3047.50 3047.50 3047.00 3047.50 228          
4   1592194660 3048.00 3048.00 3047.50 3048.00 136          
5   1592194670 3048.00 3048.00 3046.50 3046.50 174          
6   1592194680 3046.50 3046.50 3045.00 3045.00 134          
7   1592194690 3045.50 3046.00 3044.00 3045.00 43           
8   1592194700 3045.00 3045.50 3045.00 3045.00 214          
9   1592194710 3045.50 3045.50 3045.50 3045.50 8            
10  1592194720 3045.50 3046.00 3044.50 3044.50 152
    .......
    .......
19999   1591594660 3048.00 3048.00 3047.50 3048.00 136
```

The sample output as below:

```
3048.50 2140 2020-06-13 04:34:00
3050.50 67 2020-06-13 04:35:00
3049.50 1489 2020-06-13 04:36:00
3047.50 987 2020-06-13 04:37:00
......
3099.50 2 2020-06-14 04:34:00
```

Below is my stupid code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect( host = "localhost",
                        user="root",
                        passwd="root",
                        db="demo")

sql = "SELECT TIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME FROM demo_table;"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

# 12 hours for 1000 records
for i in range(1000, 20000-1000,1):
    high_price = df.loc[i,['high']][0]
    df_1000 = df.loc[i-1000:i]
    df_high = df_1000[df_1000['high']>high_price]
    high_count = df_high.shape[0]
    df_last = df_high.tail(1)
    time_dt = pd.Timestamp(df_last['TIME'], unit='s')
    print(high_price, high_count, time_dt )
```

Comment: can you add sample output?

Comment: @Datanovice Of course, sample output already added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend to read the CSV and set TIME as the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, delim_whitespace=True)
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], unit='s')
df.set_index('TIME', inplace=True)
```

In case you would simply like to reduce the time intervals to another one (so for example to go from the current 1 minute to 5 minutes), you can easily re-sample it using [Dataframe.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method:

```
# Tells what the aggregation should do for each column 
colls_agg = {'OPEN': lambda x: x.iloc[0], 
             'HIGH': 'max', 
             'LOW': 'min', 
             'CLOSE': lambda x: x.iloc[-1], 
             'VOLUME': 'sum'}

def get_summary(df, time_interval):
    # Tells what the aggregation should do for each column
    return df.resample(pd.Timedelta(time_interval)).agg(colls_agg)
```

If you would like that each line of your dataframe corresponds to the summary of the last X minutes (which I believe is what you want), you need to recalculate it for each line, as shown below.

```
colls_agg = {'OPEN': lambda x: x.iloc[0], 
             'HIGH': 'max', 
             'LOW': 'min', 
             'CLOSE': lambda x: x.iloc[-1], 
             'VOLUME': 'sum'}

def recompute_summary_line(line, full_df, time_interval):
    """Recomputes the summary for a line of the dataframe. 
    line should be a line of the dataframe, 
    full_df is the full dataframe
    time_interval is the interval of time which will be selected"""
    
    # Selects time betwen current time - time_interval 
    # until current time (including it) 
    lines_to_select = (full_df.index > line.name - time_interval) & \
                      (full_df.index <= (line.name))
    agg_value = full_df[lines_to_select].agg(colls_agg)

    # For the first few lines, this is not possible, so it returns nan
    # Since we have included the current time, it will never happen. 
    # If you do NOT to include the current time, you might use this.
    if agg_value.empty:
        return pd.Series({'OPEN': np.nan, 'HIGH': np.nan, 
                          'LOW': np.nan, 'VOLUME': np.nan})

    return agg_value

def recompute_summary (df, time_interval):
    """Given a dataframe df, recomputes the summary for the 
    current time of each row using the information from the the previous 
    interval given in time_interval (for example '5min', '30s')"""
    
    # Use df.apply to apply it in each line of the dataframe
    return df.apply(lambda x: recompute_summary_line(
        x, df, pd.Timedelta(time_interval)), axis='columns')

recompute_summary(df, '1min')
recompute_summary(df, '12h')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a pity, It doesn't work, I got an error of `KeyError: 'TIME'`

Comment: I do not have your file, so I could not copy what you used. You should just use the code you provided to read the file.

Comment: Just keep the part: $import pandas as pd import pymysql conn = pymysql.connect( host = "localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="demo") sql = "SELECT TIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME FROM demo_table;" df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)$ and start my code from $df['TIME'] ...$